# Error adding widget to homescreen -- The Linked Program is no Longer Installed on Your Phone

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating an android widget and when I run my widget, after cleaning my workspace and deleting any previous instance of that widget from my device via the Application Manager, when I go to add the widget to my device, I get the error that "The linked program is no longer installed on your phone".

Before this started happening, I used to get this error:

```
10-06 08:58:29.448: D/AndroidRuntime(6994): Shutting down VM
10-06 08:58:29.448: W/dalvikvm(6994): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2012)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1101)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4333)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget-1.apk]
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2003)
10-06 08:58:29.458: E/AndroidRuntime(6994):     ... 10 more
10-06 08:58:36.535: W/dalvikvm(7066): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<receiver android:name=".AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
</intent-filter>

<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff"/>

</receiver>

<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilder.WidgetConfig"     android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />     
</intent-filter> 

</activity>   

<activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"/>


</application>

</manifest>
```

I only have two classes:
AFBWidget.java:

```
import java.util.Random;

import com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.R;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AFBWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomInt = r.nextInt(1000000000);
    String rand = String.valueOf(randomInt);

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int awID = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        v.setTextViewText(R.id.tvwidgetUpdate, rand);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, v);
    }

}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Thanks for checking us out!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

widgetConfig.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.R;


public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText info;
AppWidgetManager awm;
Context c;
int awID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    c = WidgetConfig.this;
    info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etwidgetconfig);
    //Getting info about the widget that launched this Activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
        awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
                );
    }else{
        finish();
    }
    awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String e = info.getText().toString();

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, e);

    Intent in = new Intent(c, WidgetConfig.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bwidgetOpen, pi);

    awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);

    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

    finish();
}


}
```

I can't figure out how to fix this error no matter what I do. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FINALLY FIXED IT AFTER 3 DAYS! Ok, so it was indeed because my two java classes were in a default package. So to fix that, since my classes were being accessed via a different package, I created a new package that was my app (com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget) and then moved the classes into there and now it works with no problemos! :DD Thanks for all you've done I really do apperciate it!

Answer (score 1):

DO the following modifications in you manifest:

remove this line:

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Your widget configuration acitivity cant be the launcher acitivity! The widget config is only launched once the user selects your widget form widget list, and its handled by the Andorid OS.

If you want a launcher acitivity it has to be something else and you wont be able to add widgets from it. Widgets can only be added like i previously described, when the user clicks your widget from the widget list(where you optionally open the config)

Once that is cleared, also remove:

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

This line makes no sense? You declared your .AFBWidget as a receiver a few lines above, and now you are saying that its an acitivity which it certainly isnt. ;) as it is extending AppWidgetProvider.

Also when declaring you receiver add the full package name like this:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.AFBWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"> ....
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I get the error that "The linked program is no longer installed on your phone" and logcat doesn't show anything nor does the widget show up on the device screen at all

Comment: This is on a real device but I'll try it on an emulator too and let you know

Comment: I still get the class not found exception as posted in the question :/

Comment: Does it make a different that AFBWidget.java is in a default package?

Comment: I think it does but if so, how can I change it or if not what do I change in my android:name

Comment: I FINALLY FIXED IT AFTER 3 DAYS! Ok, so it was indeed because my two java classes were in a default package. So to fix that, since my classes were being accessed via a different package, I created a new package that was my app (com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget) and then moved the classes into there and now it works with no problemos! :DD Thanks for all you've done I really do apperciate it!

Comment: Glad you've fixed it.